# Group by, having using where in condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, having, where-in, exact-match

```
SeqNo   ProfileId   MenuId
--------------------------
 1      P1001        1001
 2      P1001        1002
 3      P1001        1004
 4      P1001        1005
 5      P1001        1006
 6      P1001        1007
 7      P1001        1008
 8      P1001        1009
 9      P1001        1010
10      P1002        1001
11      P1002        1002
12      P1002        1003
13      P1002        1004
14      P1002        1005
```

The scenario is to check whether a given `ProfileId` exists or not for specific set of `MenuId`.

Suppose my input `MenuId` set is `(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005)`, then it must return exact matching condition which is `P1002`.

If MenuId set is `(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010)` then it must return `P1001`.

But if I use `group by` and `where in` condition, it returns both `P1001, P1002`.

How can I get exact matching condition for above scenarios?

Comment: Hey @P.Salmon, Actually every time we are creating new unique profile based on menuid set, so that before creating it we have to check whether exact same set of menuid is already mapped to any profile or not ???

Comment: What version of sql server are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match *exact* matching profiles, then one option is to aggregate and assert both the distinct and total counts:

```
SELECT ProfileId
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ProfileId
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN MenuId NOT IN (1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005)
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND
    COUNT(DISTINCT MenuId) = 5 AND
    COUNT(*) = 5;
```

### Demo

The three conditions in the `HAVING` clause assert that:

- No menu items *other* than 1001 to 1005 inclusive appear for that profile
- There are 5 distinct menu items for that profile
- There are only 5 total menu items for that profile

Comment: thanx @Tim for comment, but still it returns both **ProfileId** for the same query suggested by you.

Comment: Bingo !!! thanx @Tim it's work as expected, can you please explain it ???

Comment: I did explain it.  You just assert that you don't see anything other than 1001 to 1005, then you assert that you saw 5, and only 5, distinct menu items.  Collectively, this implies that only 1001 to 1005, and nothing else, are present.

Answer (score 0):

I quite like a string comparison approach for the set. If you have string_agg then you can use that otherwise the stuff/xml path method is also good

for example

```
drop table t
go
create table t(
SeqNo  int ,ProfileId  varchar(5),  MenuId varchar(4));
go
insert into t values
( 1  ,    'P1001'     ,   1001),
( 2  ,    'P1001'     ,   1002),
( 3  ,    'P1001'     ,   1004),
( 4  ,    'P1001'     ,   1005),
( 5  ,    'P1001'     ,   1006),
( 6  ,    'P1001'     ,   1007),
( 7  ,    'P1001'     ,   1008),
( 8  ,    'P1001'     ,   1009),
( 9  ,    'P1001'     ,   1010),
(10  ,    'P1002'     ,   1001),
(11  ,    'P1002'     ,   1002),
(12  ,    'P1002'     ,   1003),
(13  ,    'P1002'     ,   1004),
(14  ,    'P1002'     ,   1005);

select s.profileid
from
(
select  distinct t.profileid,
        maskdetail = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + t1.menuid
          FROM t t1
          WHERE t1.profileid = t.profileid
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
from t

) s 
where s.maskdetail = concat('1001',',',1002,',',1003,',',1004,',','1005')

profileid
---------
P1002

(1 row(s) affected)
```

You do have to ensure that both your set and the data are in order.